# Horizontal Div Alignment with Stacked Images

Tags: css, html

I have four divs (and some img's), specified as such:

```
<div class="c">
    <div class="m">
        <img class="i" />
        <img class="i" />
        <img class="i" />
    </div>
    <div class="p">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="r">
</div>
```

The div's are meant to appear as follows:

```
______________________________
|  div.m             | div.p  |
|                    |        |
|____________________|________|
|  div.r                      |
|                             |
|_____________________________|
```

The img's are meant to be stacked on top of each other (we're manipulating their z-indexes for various effects) inside of div.m.  The stacking is achieved with

```
postion: absolute;
```

Originally, the positions of div.m and div.p were swapped, and placing them inside div.c and using a

```
float: left;
```

on div.p made everything flow fine.

Now I've swapped their positions, but no combination of float/clear/position/display will get them to align horizontally - they both just stack top left.  What's more, so does div.r.  I've been able to get the effect I want by specifying everything absolutely, but that just feels wrong.

Why isn't float et. al working?  It feels like it may have to do with that image stacking, but I don't know for sure, nor how to fix it.

Here is the CSS I thought should work (because it did when m and p were swapped in the markup, and the float was applied to p) but which isn't:

```
.m
{
    float: left;
}
.i
{
    position: absolute;
}
.r
{
    float: left;
}
```

**UPDATE:**  I am an idiot.  I realize this is not news nor much of an "update" to those of you who know me, but...  Turns-out there was some other CSS styling the size on div.p a little larger, so that the two (div.m and div.p) couldn't both fit in the outer div.  Ugh.  Sorry for the wild goose chase.  All the same, I'll be accepting the answer below as the inline-block and the piece about the img's not taking space were key to me getting here...

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle demonstrating what you've tried?

Comment: Might be worth reading these sitepoint articles on [`float`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/float) and [`position`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position)

Comment: your CSS is missing a float for `.p`, so he's just a regular block element, that's what causing him to take a whole line for himself. below `.m`. also you dont have a `i` class in your markup.

Comment: I took neoMagic's images from below, and created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ujXZH/4/) jsFiddle of the issue.  You can't see it without developer tools, but "control-panel" and results are buried under the cats, instead of being positioned to the right as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a wrapper element for the images. As they are positioned absolutely, they won't take space (are no block). This wrapper should get the same dimensions as the images in the DIV with class m. Let's give it class "w" :) Like this:

```
.w { width:150px; height:120px; display:inline-block; }
```

It should get display:inline-block in order to prevent the DIV to get the full width.

[Try out this full example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BwzY6/)

Comment: I see that this looks correct, but it doesn't translate to my page for some reason.  Also, why do I need a seperate "w", can't "m" serve as the wrapper?

Comment: Actually, your comment about the images taking no space may have been key.  It looks like I was able to use the m class also as the wrapper. After I play with ita little more I think I'll be marking this as the answer.